# Saving temporary images to static directory or not in django

Tags: django

I'm doing a project where i create some images using seaborn and then i display them to the user. Since the images will last only a couple of hours it's a good way to save them into the `static` directory or should I behave differently? If so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using below code:

```
import uuid

# generate unique name of image file
unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4())

# assign file name
model.field_name = unique_filename  # model is model object

# save image in temp directory
model.field_name.save(unique_filename, file_content)

# image URL
file_url = settings.MEDIA_FILES + '/folder_name/' + unique_filename

model.save()
```

It will save the file into the folder.

**EDIT**

get image from front end:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

# get file from json data
format_image, img_str = image_data['file'].split(';base64,')

# file content
file_content = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(img_str))
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how can i access to the file created this way from the frontend